# Bandwidth Monitoring

Tags: monitoring, bandwidth

I have a VPS that for the 1st time in 4 years went over the monthly cap.
The machine was just rebuilt by the provider and since bandwidth has never been an issue before the rebuild I was wondering if there is a way of monitoring usage so that I could potentially track down the reason for this usage?
Ideally I would like to reset at the start of a new month.

Thanks